# How to show that $f(z)= 1/(z-a)$ is periodic with period $2\pi i$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

From Ahlfor's book, Complex Analysis, page 149:

"The particular function $1/(z-a_j)$ has the period $2\pi i$."

How can one see this is true?
I tried writing $z$ as $|z| e^{i \arg{z}}$ and using the definition of periodic $f(z+\omega)=f(z)$, but I can't seem to work out the details this way.

Comment: If the period is $2i\pi$, you need to try $f(z+2i\pi)$ !

Comment: Here period is meant in the cohomological sense (what you get when you integrate a form on a fundamental cycle)

Comment: I have added some details to my answer, justifying the (admittedly confusing) terminology.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ahlfors is talking about a different kind of period there, which are not the same as periods in the definition of a periodic functions. Indeed, on page 147 Ahlfors defines periods to be the values of the contour integrals
$$\int_{\gamma_i}f\,dz,$$
where $\gamma_i$ are a homology basis of the domain. In the case of the domain $\Omega'=\{0<|z-a_j|<\delta_j\}$ discussed in the cited passage, homology basis has precisely one element $\gamma$, which is a counterclockwise loop $\gamma$ going once around $a_j$ contained in $\Omega'$ (we would also take a clockwise loop, which would change the sign of the result, but nothing else), and therefore we have exactly one period of $f(z)=\frac{1}{z-a_j}$, namely
$$\int_\gamma\frac{dz}{z-a_j}=2\pi i.$$

I would also like to mention that the terminology, while perhaps confusing, is not unjustified. There is a general theory explaining it, but let me explain it in a special case of a function $\frac{1}{z}$.

As you probably know, if we fix a base point $1$, then for $z_0\neq 0$ the value of an integral
$$\int_1^{z_0}\frac{dz}{z}$$
is not well-defined - indeed, it depends on the choice of the path from $1$ to $z_0$. However, we can consider a "multivalued function" which arises this way, by considering *all* possible values. This, as you can easily figure out yourself, is the logarithm function $\log z$. Moreover, while this function is not well-defined, its inverse function, $e^z$, is, and moreover it is, surprise, periodic with period $2\pi i$! You can actually figure that out directly from the fact that the integral over a circle is equal to $2\pi i$.

In general this is more complicated, because you have to consider integrals of multiple functions (or, more precisely, differential forms); essentially, this means that you have to choose a basis of not just *homology*, but also *cohomology*. Nevertheless, the idea is essentially the same.

Answer (score 2):

It is not periodic in that sense. By period he means the integral over a small circle about $a$, and you know this is $2\pi i$.